# How to Set threshold in Fusion Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion charts and constructing pie charts providing data in Json format. Now i want to combine data points whose values are say, less than 2% of the total, into "Others". But i am unable to find the parameter to specify that.

Comment: post your code?? what you tried so far

Comment: I couldn't find any function to set a threshold. I talked to tech support people, and they said i would need to manually combine my data points and group them as "others"

Comment: yes i understand the situation. but it will be easy if you provide the code here and js fiddle.so people can solve problem without sweat!